# Dovecot: Disconnected, connection closed, auth failed

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, dovecot

I’ve installed Postfix+Dovecot on my Ubuntu Server 22.04 (VMware Workstation 16 virtual machine). Then I’ve deployed the Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop and started to create a new mailbox in Geary. But it said “Account not created: check your sending server details”.
And I can see some interesting entries in `/var/log/mail.log`.

```bash
Jan 19 16:40:17 mailserver dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected: Connection closed (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<obfuscated>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.0.220, lip=192.168.0.212, session=<JX+MEp7ymNTAqADc>
```

Server name is `mailserver.example.com`.
User mail: obfuscateduser@example.com
SSL/TLS: no.

**`/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`**

```bash
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
```

**`/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`**

```bash
protocols = imap lmtp
```

**`10-master.conf`**

```bash
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
    }
 }
ervice auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}
```

**`/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf`**

```bash
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_username_format = %n
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

**`/etc/postfix/main.cf`**

```bash
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 3.6

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mailserver.tne.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, example.com, mailserver.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
message_size_limit = 52428800
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
smtputf8_enable = no
```

Here is the nmap result for the `mailserver`.

```bash
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  open   smtp
80/tcp  open   http
110/tcp closed pop3
143/tcp open   imap
443/tcp closed https
465/tcp closed smtps
587/tcp open   submission
993/tcp closed imaps
995/tcp closed pop3s
```

I think I should add information about users, but I don’t know in which file.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the journal:

```bash
mailserver postfix/proxymap[75657]: error: open /etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf: No such file or directory
```

So I've created that file and it's started to send messages via Roundcube!